# LDAP SAMBA : how can I reduce ldap search attributes

Tags: linux, ldap, samba

I am unable to mount a remote folder using `use net` command in windows. From the below debug messages in the `LDAP/SAMBA server`, We can see that LDAP did a search for some attributes for `uid=user1`.

But could not find any results `(nentries=0)` as user1 does not have all these attributes defined in LDAP (see below profile of user1). My question is : where these search attributes come from? and how can I reduce them to only what is needed to find user1 during the search?

Debug messages:

> Mar 23 17:59:23 myserver slapd[2530]: conn=1059 op=2 SRCH base=&quot;dc=myserver,dc=mydomain,dc=com&quot; scope=2 deref=0 filter=&quot;(&amp;(uid=user1)(objectClass=sambaSamAccount))&quot;
> Mar 23 17:59:23 myserver slapd[2530]: conn=1059 op=2 SRCH attr=uid uidNumber gidNumber homeDirectory sambaPwdLastSet sambaPwdCanChange sambaPwdMustChange sambaLogonTime sambaLogoffTime sambaKickoffTime cn sn displayName sambaHomeDrive sambaHomePath sambaLogonScript sambaProfilePath description sambaUserWorkstations sambaSID sambaPrimaryGroupSID sambaLMPassword sambaNTPassword sambaDomainName objectClass sambaAcctFlags sambaMungedDial sambaBadPasswordCount sambaBadPasswordTime sambaPasswordHistory modifyTimestamp sambaLogonHours modifyTimestamp uidNumber gidNumber homeDirectory loginShell gecos
> Mar 23 17:59:23 myserver slapd[2530]: conn=1059 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=

User1 profile in LDAP:

> user1, users, mydomain.com
> dn: uid=user1,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
> objectClass: top
> objectClass: person
> objectClass: organizationalPerson
> objectClass: posixAccount
> objectClass: shadowAccount
> objectClass: inetOrgPerson
> objectClass: sambaSamAccount
> cn: user1
> sn: user1
> uid: user1
> uidNumber: 1550
> gidNumber: 513
> homeDirectory: /home/user1
> loginShell: /bin/bash
> gecos: System User
> givenName: user1
> sambaLogonTime: 0
> sambaLogoffTime: 2147483647
> sambaKickoffTime: 2147483647
> sambaPwdCanChange: 0
> displayName: user1
> sambaSID: PDC-SRV is: S-1-5-21-1685200757-3848118661-4202727344-1001
> sambaLMPassword: FC26CDB2863917C1AAD3B435B51404EE
> sambaAcctFlags: [U]
> sambaNTPassword: 00B2C85DDFBD8CC81602D6FC7340EB0B
> sambaPwdLastSet: 1458723076
> sambaPwdMustChange: 1462611076
> userPassword:: e1NTSEF9SWpGTlFwbXY0RTJzaGNHUDdybTNWYlVuZHdsYWNWQks=
> shadowLastChange: 16883
> shadowMax: 45

Any help is appreciated.

Zak.

Comment: Are you sure the reason for not finding is the unset attributes? Your debug states a search base of `myserver,...`. this is a sibling of where the user is located within the ldap tree. So, I would expect instant failure just for this very reason.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To answer your question, I will create a user with all the attributes required by the search and test "use net" again. I will post the results.

Comment: The issue was solved. While reviewing my samba config, the output of "pdbedit -L" showed an error regarding SID. I got a fresh SID with "net getlocalsid" and corrected smbldap.conf and restarted samba. Afterwards, I deleted all LDAP entries and retried smbldap-populate. Now I can share a folder in linux with a windows user.